# In Typescript can a generic function have a optional parameter that only works for some generic types?

Tags: typescript, generics, optional-parameters, typescript-types

I have a generic function where the generic type S extends a base type, and that base type can be an empty object:

```js
type BaseState = {
   page?: number;
   perPage?: number;
};

function useTableProps<S extends BaseState>(initialState?: S = {}) {
   // function body
}
```

This produces a compiler error, because if S has non-optional properties then `{}` is no longer a valid value for S.

I can fix this by making `initialState` non-optional and forcing the caller to always supply an actual value, but is there a way to make it so that , when S only has optional properties, the function can be called with no arguments?

So I want this:

```js
type SimpleState = {
    filter?: string;
} & BaseState;

// fine, because SimpleState can be assigned by {}
const props = useTableProps<SimpleState>();

type ComplexState = {
    sort: 'ascending' | 'descending'
} & BaseState;

// compiler error - ComplexState can't be assigned
const props = useTableProps<ComplexState>();
```

I tried to do this with overloading based on generic constraints, but I don't think there's a way to express "S must be assignable from {}" as a constraint, so I couldn't find suitable declarations. I checked the docs on constraints to see if there was an "assignableFrom" constraint, but no dice! https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints

CLARIFICATION EDIT:
If S has required properties, I want to force the caller to provide a valid initial state (i.e. with the required properties set).

If S has no required properties, I want to allow the caller to provide nothing at all, and we'll initialise state with `{}`.

Comment: Do you need generics at all? If not, then the fix is easy, just remove them and it should work as expected. The problem is that `S extends BaseState` doesn't exactly mean that `S` is equal to `BaseState`. `S` can contain additional fields or with not optional fields .etc

Comment: If you still need generics the easiest solution would be to use assertion: `initialState: S = {} as S`

Comment: Another option would be using something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgZWHY0C8UDeAoKKMOAcwgH4AuKAOwFcBbAIwgCcBuAotgBVIur1mbTgF9OeUJCgBZOGAAq4CAB4FUCAA8MNACYJYAGlgA+KNnyEA2gGkoASxpQA1hBAB7AGZQe9gMbOasauHt4wJgC61Aq2EWISnnQ0fsD27k50SApwTAA2EDys7mAIKsga2hB6BvBIqOgQJgAUXI72qXC59RjUcorKZca1KGgYZhaihngAlLiieEA). Does any of these work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: You can accept a `Partial<S>` instead of an `S` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NBVRVN), and it should work.  Does that address the question fully?  If so I'll make an answer, otherwise let me know.

Comment: `Partial<S>` doesn't work because the initial state might not have required fields set. I want the initial state always to be a valid S.

Comment: Casting to S doesn't work because it allows invalid calls where the initialState is missing properties that are required in S.

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify the problem

Comment: ① Could you [edit] your example so that you are passing in `SimpleState` and `ComplexState` where appropriate instead of `BaseState`? ② *Usually* people want the compiler to *infer* the type argument to a generic function, but yours would seem to *require* someone to manually specify it in order to work.  That's not *wrong* or anything, but it's unusual, so I just want to be sure that's what you're looking for. ③ Assuming so, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mban3N) meet your needs?  (If so, ✍, if not ❓)

Comment: Thanks @jcalz - I figured this out pretty much the same time you did using `{} extends S` and different argument list type. See my answer below, produced with explanation for future coders.

Comment: @jcalz in your case `{} extends S` seems to upset the compiler, it says "Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value". Hence my more wordy approach.

Comment: That's not a TypeScript warning; presumably you're using a linter with an opinionated rule about which types you "should" or "should not" use (there's nothing wrong with using `{}`).  Not sure what that has to do with the question as asked; I'd think your particular linter settings shouldn't affect what the correct answer is.

Comment: @jcalz - good point, it was the linter!

Answer (score 0):

Actually found an answer while bathed in the light of the [Almighty Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)!

We can use some [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```js
const EMPTY = {} as const;
type Args<S> = typeof EMPTY extends S
  ? [initialState?: S]
  : [initialState: S];
```

`typeof EMPTY extends S` basically means "if {} is a valid S" so it means `S` can be assigned from `{}`.

Note that we **can't** do `{} extends S` because Typescript says not to use `{}` as a type.

Now we can use this as argument list type for our function:

```js
function useTableProps<S extends object>(...args: Args<S>) {
  // this case is guaranteed safe because args[0] 
  // will never be falsy unless S can be assigned from {}
  const initialState: S = (args[0] || {}) as S;
}
```

Now we get the desired behaviour for the function:

```js
type SimpleState = {
  filter?: string;
} & BaseState;

type ComplexState = {
  sort: 'ascending' | 'descending';
} & BaseState;

// fine - SimpleState can be assigned from {}
useTableProps<SimpleState>();
// also fine
useTableProps<SimpleState>(undefined);
// also fine
useTableProps<SimpleState>({ filter: 'active' });

// compile error
useTableProps<ComplexState>();
// compile error
useTableProps<ComplexState>(undefined);
// fine
useTableProps<ComplexState>({ sort: 'ascending' });
```

**Important caveat**: this only works if you have `strictNullChecks` turned on in your compiler, but... why wouldn't you?